# ionic doesn't keep session on serve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ionic-framework

I'm trying to save user in a session using

```
session[:user_id] = user_id # comes from ionic via get
```

but when i'm trying to send another `$http.get` request, I'm getting:

```
ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7fa8882b2ae0 not yet loaded # when I print session
nil # when I print session[:user_id]
```

If I run it from my android device it works fine.

Also tries to give it `expired_at` but still no luck.

Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:close
ETag:W/"b8f8b488bd2e233c017c98f592099e7b"
Server:thin
Set-Cookie:_MyAppServer_session=REVtSTJMYXR0TDRSVSs0VEdvNEF3a2RjR21Hei8wRFBpdFkyR3VOQTgyeXNLNGFvYjdsWjFudG9MNk51NkR2Y25DMUFmL1RsZUhmdHhUeUxTSnJPcHc9PS0tUHlTS3BYT1VOMnFSem4zS1JaeGErUT09--de9f966344e4e90810e428f53bd6cf2783ccf835; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Vary:Origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;` to the ionic js.

[XmlHttpRequest CORS POST sent without cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770359/xmlhttprequest-cors-post-sent-without-cookies)