# $http response Set-Cookie not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies, http-headers

I'm currently writing an angularjs frontend to my backend, and I'm running into a somewhat common issue:

Server sends a cookie back in a response, but is completely ignored by angular.js (can't even print out the 'Set-Cookie' value).

I've tried reading

[Set-Cookie in HTTP header is ignored with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026016/set-cookie-in-http-header-is-ignored-with-angularjs)

[Angularjs $http does not seem to understand "Set-Cookie" in the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383311/angularjs-http-does-not-seem-to-understand-set-cookie-in-the-response)

but unfortunately I've tried all the solutions there and just doesn't seem to work.

Request sent

[image: (as captured by Chrome Developer Tools)]

Response received

[image: (as captured by Chrome Developer Tools)]

I'm using angular.js (v1.2.10), and this is what I used to make the request

```
$http.post('/services/api/emailLogin',
           sanitizeCredentials(credentials), 
           {
              withCredentials: true
           }).success(function(data, status, header) {
                console.log(header('Server'));
                console.log(header('Set-Cookie'));
                console.log(header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers'));
                console.log(header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods'));
                console.log(header);
            }).then(
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                });
```

`withCredentials=true` is set on the client side before making the request.

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true` is set on the server side before returning the response.

You can clearly see `Set-Cookie` is in the response headers from Chrome Developer Tools, but printout is just

[image: (code printout)]

Only `Set-Cookie` in the response header is not being printed out.  I'm wondering why does this occur?  Is there a way for me to make sure `withCredentials=true` is indeed set (I didn't see it in the request header)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` on the server side? This resolved header issues that I was having.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: @slamborne I just tried setting

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Set-Cookie`

but that didn't work.  My guess is the value is the header I'd like to expose?

Answer (score 29):

I looked inside `$httpBackend` source code:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

  // some code

  if (xhr && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var responseHeaders = null,
        response = null;

    if(status !== ABORTED) {
      responseHeaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();

      // some code
```

It uses `XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders` to get the response headers.

After a little search I found this question: [xmlHttp.getResponseHeader + Not working for CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors)

Which made me realize that XHR by it's specification, doesn't support `SET-COOKIE`, so it have nothing to do with angular.js in particular.

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method

> #### 4.7.4 The getAllResponseHeaders() method
>
> Returns all headers from the response, **with the exception of those whose field name is Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2**.

---

#### Instead just use [`$cookies`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies):

It's a different module so you must add it to your scripts

```
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

And add it to the module dependencies:

```
 var app = angular.module('app',['ngCookies']);
```

Then just use it like so:

```
app.controller('ctrl',  function($scope, $http , $cookies, $timeout){

  $scope.request = function(){

    $http.get('/api').then(function(response){
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log($cookies.session)
      });         
    })
  }
})
```

I use `$timeout` because `$cookies` only synchronize with browser's cookies after a digest.

Comment: the timeout for syncing cookies with browser made my day.

Comment: @Ilan Frumer, this solution is broken in 1.3.14 version of Angular. Any idea ?

Comment: i can get the values, thanks to $cookies. also, is there a way to get the expiration date on these cookies?

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually need to read the cookie in Angular, or is it enough if it gets set and passed back on further requests by the browser?  While I wasn't able to get the former working, I was able to get the latter working pretty quickly with a very similar configuration.  (In particular, I was not able to use `$cookies` as @Ilan recommended.  It returned nothing.)

First things first, on the Angular side configure the `$httpProvider` to send `withCredentials` by default:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);
```

That's all you have to do in Angular.  Note that, at this point, if you attempt to read `$cookies` it will still not be able to see the cookie, but it is saved and will be passed with future AJAX calls.

Then, on the server, you need to provide a specific domain (or a set of domains) allowed under CORS, along with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.  My backend is Flask in Python with [Flask-Restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/) and it looks like this:

```
import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.decorators = [cors.crossdomain(origin='http://localhost:8100', credentials=True)]
```

That's all it took.  Now Angular (or, rather, the browser) sets the cookie and returns it with future requests completely transparently!

(The same point is made here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384207/2397068.)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1.3.14 it doesn't work anymore.

I had the same problem. I am using $resource and declared withCredentials: true.

```
 var fooRes = $resource('/address/exemple',
    {},
    {
        bar: {
            method: 'POST',
            withCredentials: true,
        }
    }
 );

 fooRes.bar({
     "stuff" : "lorem"
 }).$promise.then(function(){
     //callback
 })
```

or you can set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true".

Now the cookie will be saved and you can get using $cookie.

Hope it will help.

Comment: That doesn't work on 1.3.15, even with `withCredentials: true` in the $http request + in the $httpProvider, even after the $timeout... $cookies is always empty.

Comment: I solved it for my specific issue, not in general : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011315/read-write-the-cookies-from-an-xhr-request-response-phonegap-cordova

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your .htaccess file to allow the headers to be read.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `'access-control-expose-headers', '*'`

Example with Node API

```js
router.get('/your-route', async (req, res) => {
    //..
    res.setHeader('access-control-expose-headers', '*' );
    //..
})
```