# Missing headers in response for jQuery request with CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, header, response

I'm trying to execute CORS request with jquery buy I'm getting strange behaviour. When I use curl to execute the request everything is working fine. But when I use jQuery the things goes horribly wrong. In the "Network" tab in my browser I can inspect the request and the response from the back-end there everything is correct [image] but although I have **Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie** header I get null when I try to print it out using console.log(response.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));  When I try to print out the response headers of my ajax request in the console with **console.log(response.getAllResponseHeaders())** I get only these 3 headers:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
```

The code that I'm using to execute requests is:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8808/storage/login",
    data: {
        username: email,
        password: password,
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, response){
        console.log(response.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log(response.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
        this.setState({showAlert: true, alertMessage: "You are logged in.", alertType: "success"});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({showAlert: true, alertMessage: "Wrong email or password", alertType: "danger"});
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution.

**On server side** add these headers on the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

**Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true** This is the important one. But you can not use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * with it ! You must specify specific domain like Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com)

**On client side** update the ajax request to the following:

```
$.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8808/storage/login",
                data: {
                    username: email,
                    password: password,
                },
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data, textStatus, response){
                    console.log(response.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    console.log(response.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
                    this.setState({showAlert: true, alertMessage: "You are logged in.", alertType: "success"});
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    this.setState({showAlert: true, alertMessage: "Wrong email or password", alertType: "danger"});
                }.bind(this)
            });
```

The important part here is **xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, crossDomain: true**. For more information see how to [Set-Cookie on Browser with Ajax Request via CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221722/set-cookie-on-browser-with-ajax-request-via-cors) and after that [Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts) using jQuery

**Actually** you can not access the Set-Cookie header with response.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") so your console.log() will print every time null. You can find why here: [$http response Set-Cookie not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520890/http-response-set-cookie-not-accessible#answer-21528702) but you can inspect the cookies of the current page and check that they are set correctly.

**note: The requesting url must be HTTPS too for best answer.**

Comment: its prefect answer greats bro. +1

Comment: where on the server side should I add this code?
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Answer (score 13):

Are you making a cross domain request?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ :

> During a CORS request, the getResponseHeader() method can only access
>   simple response headers. Simple response headers are defined as
>   follows:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you
>   have to use the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. The value of
>   this header is a comma-delimited list of response headers you want to
>   expose to the client.

Comment: Yes I'm making CORS request and yes I have Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. Look at my response headers screen shot from the "Network" tab in my browser http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oYYU.png